# How can I use a for loop as a timer?

Tags: python, for-loop, timer, delay

Is there any way to use a for loop as a timer? I've tried this:

```
a = 0
for i in range(1, 10000):
    a += 1

print "Hello World"
```

But for some reason, it immediately cuts to "Hello World." I thought that Python incremented every tick or 1/1000th of a second. If so, than 10000/1000 = 10, so that for loop should last for 10 seconds right? If someone could help me understand this, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: It will take 10000 times the amount of time to increment a by 1. Something that depends on various factors (CPU clock speed, caching...). Thanks God, processors do more than one operation per millisecond :-)

Comment: Most programming languages don't impose a limit on the number of instructions that can be performed in a unit of time. If Python is able to increment in 1/1,000,000 of a second, I say let it :-)

Comment: On my old ATARI 800XL, I would write `FOR I=1 TO 500: NEXT I` to have it wait for 1 second. These times are long gone (it was in the 80s). On a PC, I observed CPU clock based timing in the game digger which only could run on my 16 MHz machine if I disabled the TURBO swich (clocking it with 8 MHz). And Turbo Pascal had its delay function measure the CPU speed at the start of the program and then using it for timing. PCs faster than about 166 MHz can't run these programs because of overflow issues. #goodoldtimes

Comment: However, when programming on microcontrollers such as ATXmega, you still have delay functions which depend on the right CPU speed set via `#define`.

Answer (score 7):

The `range` function returns a list of numbers in Python 2.x (or an iterator, in Python 3.x) in the given range. It has nothing, nothing to do with time, or ticks as you incorrectly assumed. The `a += 1` statement will execute immediately and as many times as defined by the range - which will be very quick in a modern computer.

In general, any instruction in any high level programming language will be executed as fast as the hardware permits, there isn't an implicit timer that dictates that an instruction executes for each tick of the processor - think of it, it'd be *terrible* for performance! If you need to pause the execution of a program for 10 seconds, don't use a loop for implementing a delay, instead use the [`sleep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) function for suspending the execution during a given number of seconds:

```
import time
# some code before
time.sleep(10) # sleep for 10 seconds
# some code after
```

Comment: Thanks for that information, I didn't realize that the computer would increment immediately. However, I need to do something different than time.sleep() because this is a timer for a game. I can't use pygame unfortunately, because I was told to use livewires for this particular assignment. When I use time.sleep(), it hangs up the game. Is there any way of doing a timer that can run in the background of a game?

Comment: That's a completely different problem. You'll have to use a separate thread for the timer, so it can run concurrently with the game

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `time.sleep(<number of seconds you want it to wait>)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that, as the execution time will depend on a lot of factors!

Try the `sleep` method instead:

```
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Sleep method to achieve that result.

```
time.sleep(X)
```

Where X is the number of seconds you want it to pause.

Answer (score 0):

Using your piece of code, you can try to put time.sleep(1) inside the for loop.
However, Racso and Edgar have told you a better way to do that.